# ruby + ruby on rails background scheduled database update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to update a database table every 10 minutes with results of a ruby script. The ruby script output is an hash. So i need navigate my hash result and put it in a table of my db. I want to do this within a my rails app, like a scheduled background job.

What is the best practies to do this?

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: I have not yet implemented the system, I'm considering all the possibilities and then choose the best. I would like to discuss with you the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be best using [Redis + Resque](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/queuing-ruby-resque) for this

Redis is a [`key/value pair` db storage](http://redis.io/) (basically RAM for Rails apps), and Resque is a queueing system which runs tasks to cycle through the redis values. [This RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque) will give a great overview for you:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [job scheduler for Ruby](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler).

Answer (score 0):

[Custom rake task](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks) are designed for that in Rails by default. It's not require you to include something new in your project. It's not about  scheduling. It's only about implementing code that do something behind application front-end working with model layer.

For scheduling there is many solutions starting from system cron. But your problem as it seems not about scheduling but about where code goes.

And for Resque and other queueing systems, they are needed when you initiate background task from user request and need to make it asynchronous. Not your case for now as it seems.

Comment: yes. the job must be scheduled and is not stared by user

Comment: If scheduling is like once every 10 minutes run this piece of code, cron are enough for it. Look [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/crontab-every-10-min/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a Unix based system, the best tool IMHO is the [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem:

```
every 10.minutes do
  runner "DbUpdater.update_db"
end
```

Comment: Problem is that if you don't use Capistrano for your deployment, whenever just tool that gives you ready for crontab syntax from it's own config. Not sure that this answers question asked.